# `std::call_once` always segfaults on Clang 12 on Windows (when using libstdc++)

Tags: c++, clang

I'm looking for a workaround, which will probably involve patching libstdc++ headers. Preserving binary compatibility is preferred but not obligatory, since I'm not using any precompiled C++ code except libstdc++.

I want to keep the `std::call_once` interface, since I'm trying to compile third-party code that uses is, which I don't want to change.

---

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>

int main()
{
    std::once_flag flag;
    std::call_once(flag, []{std::cout << "Once!\n";});
}
```

Running it causes a segmentation fault.

I cross-compile it to Windows from Ubuntu using Clang 12, using the standard library from MSYS2 GCC 10.2. Then I test the result with Wine (a quick test showed that it crashes on a VM too). But you should be able to reproduce the results by compiling on Windows natively (using the official Clang binaries + MSYS2 GCC, since MSYS2 doesn't have Clang 12 yet).

I compile it like this:

```
clang++-12 1.cpp --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --sysroot=/mingw64 -pthread -femulated-tls
```

If I add `-g`, GDB shows following:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000001e014dc4a in ?? () from Z:\home\holyblackcat\Sandbox\2\libgcc_s_seh-1.dll
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000001e014dc4a in ?? () from Z:\home\holyblackcat\Sandbox\2\libgcc_s_seh-1.dll
#1  0x00000000004015f3 in std::call_once<main::$_0> (__once=..., __f=...) at /mingw64/include/c++/10.2.0/mutex:721
#2  0x00000000004015b5 in main () at 1.cpp:8
(gdb) f 1
#1  0x00000000004015f3 in std::call_once<main::$_0> (__once=..., __f=...) at /mingw64/include/c++/10.2.0/mutex:721
721           __once_callable = std::__addressof(__callable);
(gdb) list
716           auto __callable = [&] {
717               std::__invoke(std::forward<_Callable>(__f),
718                             std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
719           };
720     #ifdef _GLIBCXX_HAVE_TLS
721           __once_callable = std::__addressof(__callable);
722           __once_call = []{ (*(decltype(__callable)*)__once_callable)(); };
723     #else
724           unique_lock<mutex> __functor_lock(__get_once_mutex());
725           __once_functor = __callable;
```

Clang version is:

```
# clang++-12 --version --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --sysroot=/mingw64 -pthread -femulated-tls
Ubuntu clang version 12.0.1-++20210423082613+072c90a863aa-1~exp1~20210423063319.76
Target: x86_64-w64-windows-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

GCC version (which provides libstdc++) is:

```
# g++ --version
g++.exe (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project) 10.2.0
```

Compiling the code with this GCC (which is native, not cross-compiling), produces a working code.

What's going on here? Are there any workarounds, or do I have to downgrade to Clang 11?

---

I reported a [Clang bug](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=50146).

[This bug](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=48030) looks related.

---

Here is the current segfaulting implementation of `call_once`, after preprocessing:

```
struct once_flag
{
  private:
    typedef __gthread_once_t __native_type;
    __native_type _M_once = 0;

  public:
    constexpr once_flag() noexcept = default;
    once_flag(const once_flag &) = delete;
    once_flag &operator=(const once_flag &) = delete;
    template <typename _Callable, typename... _Args>
    friend void call_once(once_flag &__once, _Callable &&__f, _Args &&...__args);
};

extern __thread void *__once_callable;
extern __thread void (*__once_call)();
extern "C" void __once_proxy(void);

template <typename _Callable, typename... _Args>
void call_once(once_flag &__once, _Callable &&__f, _Args &&...__args)
{
    auto __callable = [&]
    {
        std::__invoke(std::forward<_Callable>(__f), std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
    };
    __once_callable = std::__addressof(__callable);
    __once_call = []{(*(decltype(__callable) *)__once_callable)();};
    int __e = __gthread_once(&__once._M_once, &__once_proxy);
    if (__e)
        __throw_system_error(__e);
}
```

Comment: Works in VS2019 v16.9.4 cl.exe (compiler) v19.28.29914. Definitely a bug.

Comment: Did you try in an [AppVeyor](https://www.appveyor.com/) Windows CI instance?

Comment: @Casey Yep, there's no doubt about it being a bug. I'm hoping for a workaround, since I don't want to roll back to Clang 11. No, I didn't try AppVeyor, but I expect the results to be the same.

Comment: `#define call_once call_once_workaround` (at the right spot) and implement it yourself?

Comment: @C.M. Yes, or I could patch the header itself. But I don't feel I'm knowledgeable enough to implement it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat [here is](https://godbolt.org/z/KdnfY6T7Y) a simple implementation. It can be improved in many ways, but it will probably suffice as a workaround until proper fix in clang. If you have to use current `std:once_flag` -- implementation depends on what's in it (but I doubt it is complicated). Wrt intercepting `std::call_once` there are multiple ways... you can patch headers to redirect this call to your function defined in your own lib. You can patch your image on linker stage via linker script. All this may fail if stdlib has binary code that is already bugged (e.g. via inlining).

Comment: it probably fails because of some issue with TLS -- try changing tls model

Comment: I looked at libstc++ [code](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/mutex) -- it is slightly insane, it is using `__gthread_once()` call and all magic around it is to address the fact that it doesn't take `callable` arguments. So they set up trampolines, etc. Nothing that can't be reproduced in your own code, if needed...

Comment: @C.M. *"here is a simple implementation"* Aha thanks, looks promising. I'll try running my code with it a bit later. *"try changing tls model"* You mean `-fno-emulated-tls`? It leads to linker errors, like [those](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31617034/stdfuture-and-clang-with-stdlib-libstdc). *"it is slightly insane"* Any idea how it compares to your minimal implementation? Is all that magic just to make it faster?

Comment: *"may fail if stdlib has binary code that is already bugged"* libstdc++ is compiled with a native GCC, so it should be fine.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat _"You mean -fno-emulated-tls?"_ yes, looks like this option was made to address TLS incompatibilities between GCC and clang, I guess it isn't working 100% -- your code crashes on attempt to put a value into TLS variable.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat _"how it compares ...?"_ it relies on `__gthread_once()` implementation which is likely more efficient, uses fewer resources, etc. I doubt you will notice any difference in any but specifically created use cases. _"Is all that magic just to make it faster?"_ it is to squeeze round peg into square hole (i.e. to be able to use `__gthread_once()` which is presumably great). Also, to deal with different flavors of threading, etc... Like any library code it tries to take care of too many possibilities... :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was fixed in Clang 13, in [commit `0e4cf80`](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/0e4cf807aeaf54a10e02176498a7df13ac722b37). (Thanks [@mstorsjo](https://github.com/mstorsjo).)

---

If you're stuck with Clang 12, you can patch libstdc++ headers as a workaround. The patch below replaces global thread-local variables with `static` function-local thread-local variables, which are not affected by the bug.

To apply, save following to `patch.txt`, then do `patch /mingw64/include/c++/10.3.0/mutex patch.txt`.

```
@@ -691,8 +691,8 @@ _GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_VERSION

   /// @cond undocumented
 #ifdef _GLIBCXX_HAVE_TLS
-  extern __thread void* __once_callable;
-  extern __thread void (*__once_call)();
+  inline void *&__once_callable_get() {static __thread void *__ret; return __ret;}
+  inline void (*&__once_call_get())() {static __thread void (*__ret)(); return __ret;}
 #else
   extern function<void()> __once_functor;

@@ -703,7 +703,7 @@ _GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_VERSION
   __get_once_mutex();
 #endif

-  extern "C" void __once_proxy(void);
+  extern "C" inline void __once_proxy_inline(void) {__once_call_get()();}
   /// @endcond

   /// Invoke a callable and synchronize with other calls using the same flag
@@ -718,15 +718,15 @@ _GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_VERSION
            std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
       };
 #ifdef _GLIBCXX_HAVE_TLS
-      __once_callable = std::__addressof(__callable); // NOLINT: PR 82481
-      __once_call = []{ (*(decltype(__callable)*)__once_callable)(); };
+      __once_callable_get() = std::__addressof(__callable); // NOLINT: PR 82481
+      __once_call_get() = []{ (*(decltype(__callable)*)__once_callable_get())(); };
 #else
       unique_lock<mutex> __functor_lock(__get_once_mutex());
       __once_functor = __callable;
       __set_once_functor_lock_ptr(&__functor_lock);
 #endif

-      int __e = __gthread_once(&__once._M_once, &__once_proxy);
+      int __e = __gthread_once(&__once._M_once, &__once_proxy_inline);

 #ifndef _GLIBCXX_HAVE_TLS
       if (__functor_lock)
```

And here is an equivalent patch for GCC 10.2 (above is for 10.3):

```
@@ -691,8 +691,8 @@ _GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_VERSION
 
   /// @cond undocumented
 #ifdef _GLIBCXX_HAVE_TLS
-  extern __thread void* __once_callable;
-  extern __thread void (*__once_call)();
+  inline void *&__once_callable_get() {static __thread void *__ret; return __ret;}
+  inline void (*&__once_call_get())() {static __thread void (*__ret)(); return __ret;}
 #else
   extern function<void()> __once_functor;
 
@@ -703,7 +703,7 @@ _GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_VERSION
   __get_once_mutex();
 #endif
 
-  extern "C" void __once_proxy(void);
+  extern "C" inline void __once_proxy_inline(void) {__once_call_get()();}
   /// @endcond
 
   /// Invoke a callable and synchronize with other calls using the same flag
@@ -718,15 +718,15 @@ _GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_VERSION
            std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
       };
 #ifdef _GLIBCXX_HAVE_TLS
-      __once_callable = std::__addressof(__callable);
-      __once_call = []{ (*(decltype(__callable)*)__once_callable)(); };
+      __once_callable_get() = std::__addressof(__callable);
+      __once_call_get() = []{ (*(decltype(__callable)*)__once_callable_get())(); };
 #else
       unique_lock<mutex> __functor_lock(__get_once_mutex());
       __once_functor = __callable;
       __set_once_functor_lock_ptr(&__functor_lock);
 #endif
 
-      int __e = __gthread_once(&__once._M_once, &__once_proxy);
+      int __e = __gthread_once(&__once._M_once, &__once_proxy_inline);
 
 #ifndef _GLIBCXX_HAVE_TLS
       if (__functor_lock)
@@ -735,8 +735,8 @@ _GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_VERSION
 
 #ifdef __clang_analyzer__
       // PR libstdc++/82481
-      __once_callable = nullptr;
-      __once_call = nullptr;
+      __once_callable_get() = nullptr;
+      __once_call_get() = nullptr;
 #endif
 
       if (__e)
```

Comment: Good old "replace global static with local static" trick still works :)

Comment: @C.M. Yep! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

One way you might work around this is to take advantage of the fact that `static` variables are, since C++11, initialised in a threadsafe way.  Example:

```
#include <iostream>

void test ()
{
    std::cout << "test\n";
    static bool once = [] { std::cout << "Once!\n"; return true; } ();
    (void) once;
}

int main()
{
    test ();
    test ();
}
```

Output:

```
test
Once!
test
```

As you can see, the lambda is called the first time the static variable comes into scope (and will only be called once).

Comment: Thing is, I'm trying to compile some libraries that use `std::call_once`. So I need the same interface `std::call_once` has.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess: It is crashing due to the absence of `InitializeCriticalSectionEx()`, which means you either need to upgrade your Windows VM past XP, or specify to the compiler/linker that you are targeting Windows subsystem v5.02. No patch needed. ;-)

**Edit #1:**

Shot in the dark: Try adding `-D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0502` to your compile. It might resolve some link errors. Although mixing and matching `libstd++` versions may never work here, and the exact issues will different from one platform/compiler to the next.

As another commenter noted, the initialization of static variables local to a function are now thread-safe in C++, and this seems to have forced some changes to the way TLS works on Windows, right down to the "subsystem" level. In our own build, we pass `-Zc:threadSafeInit-` and either `/subsystem:windows,5.02` (x64) or `/subsystem:windows,5.01` (x86) to VC++, simply so that it works on XP. But it is with the understanding that these newfangled thread-safe static locals won't happen. I can only imagine what the issues might be on Windows 10, where the NT loader is multi-threaded.

**Edit #2:**

Last attempt to steal bounty, now from the OP himself: I was going down [this path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59209040/clang-cross-compilation-command-can-not-find-head-files). My current theory is that there is a bug in this new clang 11 compiler that causes it to fetch the "known" header `<iostream>` from the wrong place, despite `--sysroot`. Perhaps only when cross-compiling.

```
lstrand@styx:~/scratch/emulated-tls$ strace -o strace.out clang++-12 -E 1.exe 1.cpp --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --sysroot=/home/lstrand/scratch/emulated-tls/root > pp
clang: warning: 1.exe: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
1.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include <iostream>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
lstrand@styx:~/scratch/emulated-tls$ grep iostream strace.out 
pread64(3, "#include <iostream>\n#include <mu"..., 134, 0) = 134
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/llvm-12/lib/clang/12.0.1/include/iostream", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "./iostream", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "'iostream' file not found", 25) = 25
write(2, "#include <iostream>", 19)     = 19
lstrand@styx:~/scratch/emulated-tls$
```

Comment: The VM has Win 10, and it also crashes on Wine. *"specify to the compiler/linker that you are targeting Windows subsystem v5.02"* How do I do that?

Comment: Hmmm.  In that case, why did you use `-femulated-tls`?

Comment: Because otherwise I get linker errors. I think you're supposed to use it if you're using Clang with libstdc++, as explained e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31617034/stdfuture-and-clang-with-stdlib-libstdc).

Comment: I've added a "shot in the dark" with some perspective. I don't know what the linker errors would be for a C++ example, as I only just installed clang 12 on my Ubuntu box, and some headers seem to be missing...

Comment: `-D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0502` didn't change anything, with and without `-femulated-tls`.

Comment: Well, what is the linker error for the small example you posted?

Comment: Undefined references to `std::__once_callable` and `std::__once_call`. That's without `-femulated-tls`. If I add it, it links and crashes as usual.

Comment: If you want to download the latest MinGW to test it yourself (on Linux), I have scripts to help with that. `sudo apt install make wget tar zstd`, then `git clone https://github.com/holyblackcat/quasi-msys2`, then `cd quasi-msys2`, then `make install _gcc`. Then you should be able to use Clang with the same flags as I do, except the directory passed to `--sysroot` would have to be `<current_dir>/quasi-msys2/root/mingw64`.

Comment: *"Last attempt to steal bounty"* Hah sorry, I didn't get a notification for your edit. *"causes it to fetch the "known" header <iostream> from the wrong place"* But it works for me? You sure your `--sysroot` path is correct? If you're using my repo, it should end with `root/mingw64`, not `root`.